# R: Using regular expression to keep rows of data with 6 digits

Tags: r, regex, string

```
mydat <- data.frame(id = c("372303", "KN5232", "231244", "283472-3822"),
                    name = c("Adam", "Jane", "TJ", "Joyce"))
> mydat
           id  name
1       372303  Adam
2       KN5232  Jane
3       231244    TJ
4  283472-3822 Joyce
```

In my dataset, I want to keep the rows where `id` is a 6 digit number. For those that contain a 6 digit number followed by `-` and a 4 digit number, I just want to keep the first 6.

My final data should look like this:

```
> mydat2
               id    name
    1       372303   Adam
    3       231244     TJ
    2       283472  Joyce
```

I am using the following `grep("^[0-9]{6}$", c("372303", "KN5232", "231244", "283472-3822"))` but this does not account for the case where I want to only keep the first 6 digits before the `-`.

Comment: You have 5-digit codes in the input data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract the first standalone 6-digit number from each ID and then only keep the items with 6-digit codes only:

```r
mydat <- data.frame(id = c("372303", "KN5232", "231244", "283472-3822"),name = c("Adam", "Jane", "TJ", "Joyce"))
library(stringr)
mydat$id <- str_extract(mydat$id, "\\b\\d{6}\\b")
mydat[grepl("^\\d{6}$",mydat$id),]
```

Output:

```
      id  name
1 372303  Adam
3 231244    TJ
4 283472 Joyce
```

The `\b\d{6}\b` matches 6-digit codes as standalone numbers since `\b` are word boundaries.

Answer (score 3):

One method would be to split at `-` and then extract with `filter` or `subset`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
mydat %>% 
  separate_rows(id, sep = "-") %>% 
  filter(str_detect(id, '^\\d{6}$'))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 3 × 2
  id     name 
  <chr>  <chr>
1 372303 Adam 
2 231244 TJ   
3 283472 Joyce
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also extract all 6-digit numbers with a very simple regex (`\\d{6}`), convert to numeric (as I would expect you would anyway) and remove `NA`'s.

E.g.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

mydat |> 
  mutate(id = as.numeric(str_extract_all(id, "\\d{6}"))) |>
  na.omit()
```

Output:

```r
      id  name
1 372303  Adam
3 231244    TJ
4 283472 Joyce
```